EF Core and DDD with composite keys on database
I'm trying to configure EF Core to my entities, in the database I have a table like this:



Coluna
Tipo




InspectionId
int


QuestionGroup
varchar


Question
varchar


Answer
varchar


Observation
varchar


CreatedAt
datetime



I have a composite primary key, made up of InspectionId, QuestionGroup, Question, Answer.
I tried to create my entity like this:
public class Checklist
{
    public Checklist(ChecklistId id, string observation, int userId, DateTime createdAt)
    {
        Id = id;
        CreatedAt = createdAt;
        Observation = observation;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public ChecklistId Id { get; set; }
    public string Observation { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class ChecklistId
{
    public ChecklistId(int inspectionId, string questionGroup, string question, string answer)
    {
        InspectionId = inspectionId;
        QuestionGroup = questionGroup;
        Question = question;
        Answer = answer;
    }

    public int InspectionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionGroup { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

How can I configure EF Core to support this entity?
I tried with this configuration, but it failed:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Checklist>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id.InspectionId, e,Id.QuestionGroup, e.Id.Question, e.Id.Answer });

        entity.OwnsOne(e => e.Id, id =>
        {
            id.Property(i => i.InspectionId).HasColumnName("InspectionId");
            id.Property(i => i.QuestionGroup).HasColumnName("QuestionGroup");
            id.Property(i => i.Question).HasColumnName("Question");
            id.Property(i => i.Answer).HasColumnName("Answer");
        });

        // ... others properties
    });
}

Project is created with

.NET 8
SQL Server 2008

I cannot change the database to the table have a unique id like a Guid, is it possible to configure EF Core with composite keys using ids on domain side?

It's not a very good idea to have a composite PK made up of 4 (of 6) columns of the table - and most definitely not if it contains varchar-columns. You should preferably have a single, unique and identifying Id of some sort and put the PK on that column instead

Just put all properties involved in a key directly on entity class:
public class Checklist
{
    public string Observation { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int InspectionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionGroup { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

and context configuration:
entity.HasKey(e => new { e.InspectionId, e.QuestionGroup, e.Question, e.Answer });

